# Visualforce page using lightning style

Tags: salesforce1-app

On Andriod, desktop IE, Chrome and FireFox or Apple Safari we can architect the page to have 2 major areas, 
header and body.  The header div has two buttons, Save and Cancel, The body div has all the input fields. Now, on all the previous mentioned browsers,
as the user scrolls up and down the page, the buttons will move with the visible portion of the page so no matter where the window stops scrolling, the SAVE and CANCEL buttons are always visible. This also works on an Andriod device running Salesforce1.

THE PROBLEM:

Using an iPad or iPhone, Salesforce1 does not change the position of the buttons.  The user always has to scroll back to the top of the page to save or cancel. Safari on an iPhone or iPad does move the buttons.  Does anyone have a workaround for this? Are there known issues using UIWebView on Apple that are preventing the us from moving the buttons? Also, UIWebViewer seems to not use the meta tag "Viewport" which would allow us to asjust the position?